# How can I install dask[complete] manually?

Tags: installation, dask

I want to use the package "Dask", but there is one problem.
"Dask dataframe requirements are not installed."
Obviously, we can use pip install "dask[dataframe]" or pip install "dask[complete]".
However, in the secured server where I work, there is no internet connection.
So, I transfer the file of package and install manually.
But, I cannot find the package dask[dataframe] for downloading.
How can I install the rest of packages manually without internet connection?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the setup.py requirements file in the dask repository to see which dependencies it requires.